# Disable SSL certificate verification in Scrapy

Tags: python, ssl, scrapy

I am currently struggling with an issue I am having with Scrapy. Whenever I used Scrapy to scrape an HTTPS site where the certificate's CN value matches the server's domain name, Scrapy works great! On the other hand, though, whenever I try scraping a site where the certificate's CN value does NOT match the server's domain name, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 415, in dataReceived
    self._write(bytes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 554, in _write
    sent = self._tlsConnection.send(toSend)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1270, in send
    result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, buf, len(buf))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 926, in wrapper
    callback(Connection._reverse_mapping[ssl], where, return_code)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1055, in infoCallback
    return wrapped(connection, where, ret)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1154, in _identityVerifyingInfoCallback
    verifyHostname(connection, self._hostnameASCII)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/service_identity/pyopenssl.py", line 30, in verify_hostname
    obligatory_ids=[DNS_ID(hostname)],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/service_identity/_common.py", line 235, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Invalid DNS-ID.")
exceptions.ValueError: Invalid DNS-ID.
```

I have looked through as much documentation as I can, and as far as I can tell Scrapy does not have a way to disable SSL certificate verification. Even the documentation for the Scrapy Request object (which I would assume is where this functionality would lie) has no reference:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request
[https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/request/**init**.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/http/request/__init__.py)

There are also no Scrapy settings which address the issue:

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/settings.html

Short of using Scrapy by source and modifying the source as needed, does anyone have any ideas for how I can disable the SSL certificate verification?

Thank you!

Comment: Looks to me from the documentation that you can modify the `DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS` or `DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS_BASE` settings to change the way scrapy will handle https. From there you might have to create your own modified `HttpDownloadHandler` that can get past the error you're receiving.

Comment: /me bonks head against desk. That certainly looks hopeful. Can you write this up as an answer so I can accept, and then add the code I used for others for future reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation you linked for [the settings](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/settings.html), it looks like you would be able to modify the `DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS` setting.

From the docs:

```
"""
    A dict containing the request download handlers enabled by default in
    Scrapy. You should never modify this setting in your project, modify
    DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS instead.
"""

DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS_BASE = {
    'file': 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.file.FileDownloadHandler',
    'http': 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http.HttpDownloadHandler',
    'https': 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http.HttpDownloadHandler',
    's3': 'scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.s3.S3DownloadHandler',
}
```

Then in your settings, something like this:

```
""" 
    Configure your download handlers with something custom to override
    the default https handler
"""
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    'https': 'my.custom.downloader.handler.https.HttpsDownloaderIgnoreCNError',
}
```

So by defining a custom handler for the `https` protocol, you should be able to handle the error you're getting and allow scrapy to continue with its' business.

Comment: This is great, and looks to address specifically what I'm having issues with. I'm going to monkey around with the code and see if I can get this working and post my solution here! Thanks!

Comment: @MoarCodePlz did you come to a solution? Any interesting in posting some links?