# How to disable SSL verification on Python Scrapy?

Tags: python, ssl, scrapy

I am writing data scraping scripts for past 3 years in PHP.

This is simple PHP script

```
$url = 'https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/corp_public/CORPSEARCH.SELECT_ENTITY';
$fields = array(
    'p_entity_name' => urlencode('AAA'),
    'p_name_type' => urlencode('A'),
    'p_search_type' => urlencode('BEGINS')
);
//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print curl_error($ch) . '<br>';
print curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . '<br>';
print $result;
```

It works fine only if `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` is `false`. It returns empty response if we enable `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` or if use `http` instead of `https`.

But, I have to do this same project in Python Scrapy, here is same code in Scrapy.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http.request import Request
import urllib
from appext20.items import Appext20Item

class Appext20Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "appext20"
    allowed_domains = ["appext20.dos.ny.gov"]
    DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
    'https': 'my.custom.downloader.handler.https.HttpsDownloaderIgnoreCNError',}
    def start_requests(self):
        payload = {"p_entity_name": 'AMEB', "p_name_type": 'A', 'p_search_type':'BEGINS'}
        url = 'https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/corp_public/CORPSEARCH.SELECT_ENTITY'
        yield Request(url, self.parse_data, method="POST", body=urllib.urlencode(payload))

    def parse_data(self, response):
        print('here is repos')
        print response
```

It returns empty response. it needs to be disabled SSL Verification.

Please pardon my lack of knowledge in Python Scrapy, I have searched a lot about it but didn't find any solution.

Comment: You're using "http://" scheme in your spider code. I believe you want to use `url = 'https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/corp_public/CORPSEARCH.SELECT_ENTITY'`. Besides that, scrapy 1.1+ by default also skips peer certificate verification. Can you share you logs and tell us where you are having trouble?

Comment: @paultrmbrth sorry for confusion, I am already using https in scrapy code ... but it returns empty response... can you also tell me where to see logs? are you talking about the full output in terminal after I run code? if so, here is full output after I run my scrapy code ... http://www.beetxt.com/printable.php?view=Jnw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import FormRequest


import urllib
from appext20.items import Appext20Item
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class Appext20Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "appext20"
    allowed_domains = ["appext20.dos.ny.gov"]
    payload = {"p_entity_name": 'AME', "p_name_type": 'A', 'p_search_type':'BEGINS'}

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/corp_public/CORPSEARCH.SELECT_ENTITY'
        return [ FormRequest(url,
                     formdata= self.payload,
                     callback=self.parse_data) ]

    def parse_data(self, response):
        print('here is response')
        questions = HtmlXPathSelector(response).xpath("//td[@headers='c1']")
        # print questions
        all_links = [] 
        for tr in questions:
            temp_dict = {}
            temp_dict['link'] = tr.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            temp_dict['title'] = tr.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            all_links.extend([temp_dict])
        print (all_links)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having a look at this page: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/settings.html it would appear that you can alter the way that the module behaves and change settings on various handlers.

I also believe this is a duplicate question from: [Disable SSL certificate verification in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950694/disable-ssl-certificate-verification-in-scrapy)

HTHs

Thanks,

//P

Comment: I have already seen the answer from the question you mentioned .. But I am not sure where to write that line of code. do you know that?