# how to specific TLS version or disable TLS verify in scrapy

Tags: python, ssl, scrapy

For the site: https://www.cnbanbao.cn/

I tried this command on my MAC

```
openssl s_client  -connect www.cnbanbao.cn:443 -msg
```

And the result:

```
>>> TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 00c3], ClientHello
...
<<< TLS 1.2 Handshake [length 0051], ServerHello
...
<<< TLS 1.0 Handshake [length 0a4a], Certificate
...
<<< TLS 1.0 Handshake [length 0004], ServerHelloDone
...
>>> TLS 1.0 Handshake [length 0106], ClientKeyExchange
...
>>> TLS 1.0 ChangeCipherSpec [length 0001]
...
>>> TLS 1.0 Handshake [length 0010], Finished
```

I think the problem may be that the site use **TLS1.2** for **ServerHello** but **TLS1.0** for TLS **Handshake**, which cause the problem when I try to download the site in **scrapy**

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.cnbanbao.cn/'
2019-01-24 11:49:57 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.cnbanbao.cn/> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
2019-01-24 11:49:58 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.cnbanbao.cn/> (failed 2 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
2019-01-24 11:49:59 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.cnbanbao.cn/> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
```

I tried to specific the TLS1.0 version: [SSL issue when scraping website](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1429), it seems not work

I also tried to [Disable SSL certificate verification in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950694/disable-ssl-certificate-verification-in-scrapy), But I don't know how to define a **HttpsDownloaderIgnoreCNError** to disable ssl verification

Any idea to make the follwing command work?

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.cnbanbao.cn/'
```